# Why is safari does not react to my media queries?

Tags: sass, safari, responsive-design, media-queries, node-sass

I have a bunch of queries in my page. Chrome responds to all of them and Safari just won't render almost all of them and I'm wondering why. I can't even see them in Safari DevTools.

I thought that maybe there's something going on with root font-size or maybe browser scale so I set font-size to 100% and added specific value for breakpoints but I didn't worked out.

Here are queries from my .scss

@mixin respond ($breakpoint){

```
    @if $breakpoint == ipadLand {
        @media screen and (width: 1024px) and (height: 768px) {

            body {
                font-size: 75%;
            }

            .button_text{
                font-size: 0.9rem;
            }

            .contacts_section_row{
                top: 4.5rem;
            }

            .contact_header{
                margin-top: 2rem;
            }

            .skills_container_row3{
                margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
              }

            .contacts_section_col{
                width: $picture_width;
            }

            .contacts_section_row{
                width: calc(#{$picture_width} * 3);
            }

            .vk_picture{
                height: $picture_width;
                width: $picture_width;
                margin: auto;
              }
              
              .tg_picture{
                height: $picture_width;
                width: $picture_width;
                margin: auto;
              }
              
              .hh_picture{
                height: $picture_width;
                width: $picture_width;
                margin: auto;
              }
        
        }}

        @if $breakpoint == ipadpro12_port {

            @media screen and (width: 1024px) and (height: 1366px){

                $contact_section_height: 20rem;

                body {
                    font-size: 120%;
                }
                
                .name_text{
                    font-size: 2.5rem;
                    padding-top: 1rem;
                    padding-left: 5vw;
                }

                .role_text{
                    font-size: 1.7rem;
                    padding-top: 0.6rem;
                    padding-left: 1rem;
                }

                .main_div{
                    height: 985.3px;
                    //height: calc((100vh + (#{$head_div_height} * 2)));
                }

                .photo_box{
                    height: 40%;
                    width: 100vw;
                }

                .photo{
                    margin: 0 auto;
                    margin-top: 50px;
                    width: auto;
                    height: 85%;

                }

                .vk_picture{
                    height: $picture_width;
                    width: $picture_width;
                    margin: auto;
                  }
                  
                  .tg_picture{
                    height: $picture_width;
                    width: $picture_width;
                    margin: auto;
                  }
                  
                  .hh_picture{
                    height: $picture_width;
                    width: $picture_width;
                    margin: auto;
                  }

                .contacts_section_col{
                    width: calc((#{$picture_width} * 3) / 3);
                }

                .contacts_section_row{
                    margin-top: 1rem;
                    width: calc(#{$picture_width} * 3)
                }

                .contact_header{
                    text-align: center;
                    height: auto;
                    width: inherit;
                    margin: 0 auto;
                    margin-top: 1rem;
                    transform: translate(0); 
                }

                .skills_container_row{
                    font-size: 2.5rem;
                    margin: 0px;
                }

                .skillsandprojects-col-one{
                    font-size: 2rem;
                    height: auto;
                    text-align: left;
                }


                .skillsandprojects_container{
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 40%;
                    right: 0;
                    left: 0;
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 35%;
                    margin: 0;
                    background-color: white;
                    border: none;
                }

                .contacts_section{
                    position: relative;
                    bottom: calc(100vh - (#{$main_div_height} + #{$head_div_height} + #{$contact_section_height}));
                    width: 100vw;
                    height: $contact_section_height;
                    //background-color: blue; }
                    //background-color: $header_text_color; 
                  }

                .button_text{
                    font-size: 1.6rem;
                }

                .skillsandprojects_container2{
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 75%;
                    right: 0;
                    left: 0;
                    height: 35%;
                    width: 100%;
                }

                .skills_container_row3{
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 39px;
                    border: none;
                    margin-bottom: 1rem;
                  }

                }}

        @if $breakpoint == ipad_port {

            @media screen and (width: 768px) and (height: 1024px){

                body {
                    font-size: 70%;
                }
                
                .name_text{
                    font-size: 1.5rem;
                    padding-top: 2rem;
                    padding-left: 5vw;
                }

                .role_text{
                    font-size: 0.7rem;
                    padding-top: 0.6rem;
                    padding-left: 0.5rem;
                }

                .main_div{
                    height: calc((100vh - (#{$head_div_height} + #{$contact_section_height})));
                    //height: 985.3px;
                    //height: calc((100vh + (#{$head_div_height} * 2)));
                }

                .photo_box{
                    height: 40%;
                    width: 100vw;
                }

                .photo{
                    margin: 0 auto;
                    margin-top: 25px;
                    width: auto;
                    height: 75%;

                }

                .vk_picture{
                    height: $picture_width;
                    width: $picture_width;
                    margin: auto;
                  }
                  
                  .tg_picture{
                    height: $picture_width;
                    width: $picture_width;
                    margin: auto;
                  }
                  
                  .hh_picture{
                    height: $picture_width;
                    width: $picture_width;
                    margin: auto;
                  }

                .contacts_section_col{
                    width: calc((#{$picture_width} * 3) / 3);
                }

                .contacts_section_row{
                    width: calc(#{$picture_width} * 3)
                }

                .contact_header{
                    text-align: center;
                    height: auto;
                    width: inherit;
                    margin: 0 auto;
                    transform: translate(0); 
                }

                .skills_container_row{
                    font-size: 1.5rem;
                    margin: 0px;
                }

                .skillsandprojects-col-one{
                    font-size: 1.8rem;
                    height: auto;
                    text-align: left;
                }


                .skillsandprojects_container{
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 40%;
                    right: 0;
                    left: 0;
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 35%;
                    margin: 0;
                    background-color: white;
                    border: none;
                }

                .button_text{
                    font-size: 0.79rem;
                }

                .skillsandprojects_container2{
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 75%;
                    right: 0;
                    left: 0;
                    height: 35%;
                    width: 100%;
                }

                .skills_container_row3{
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 39px;
                    border: none;
                  }

                  .contacts_section{
                      margin-top: 6rem;
                  }

                }}

    @if $breakpoint == phone {

        @media screen and (max-width: 573px) and (max-height: 926px){
            
            .name_text{
                font-size: 1.5rem;
                padding-top: 2rem;
                padding-left: 5vw;
            }

            .role_text{
                font-size: 0.7rem;
                padding-top: 0.6rem;
                padding-left: 0.5rem;
            }

            .main_div{
                height: 985.3px;
                //height: calc((100vh + (#{$head_div_height} * 2)));

            }

            .contact_header{
                text-align: center;
                height: auto;
                width: inherit;
                //height: $contacts_section_header_height;
                transform: translate(0);
                //margin: 0 auto;
                margin-bottom: 0.2rem; }

            .photo_box{
                height: 40%;
                width: 100vw;
            }
            

            .vk_picture{
                width: 3.437rem;
                height: 3.437rem;
            }

            .tg_picture{
                width: 3.437rem;
                height: 3.437rem;
            }

            .hh_picture{
                width: 3.437rem;
                height: 3.437rem;
            }

            .contacts_section_col{
                width: calc((#{3.437rem} * 3) / 3);
            }

            .contacts_section_row{
                width: calc(#{3.437rem} * 3)
            }

            .skills_container_row{
                font-size: 1.5rem;
                margin: 0px;
            }

            .skillsandprojects-col-one{
                font-size: 1.8rem;
                height: auto;
                text-align: left;
            }


            .skillsandprojects_container{
                position: absolute;
                top: 40%;
                right: 0;
                left: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 35%;
                margin: 0;
                background-color: white;
                border: none;
            }

            .button_text{
                font-size: 0.9rem;
            }

            .skillsandprojects_container2{
                position: absolute;
                top: 75%;
                right: 0;
                left: 0;
                height: 35%;
                width: 100%;
            }

            .skills_container_row3{
                width: 100%;
                height: 39px;
                //height: calc((100% - #{$skills_head-row})/3);
                border: none;
              }
            
        }
}

@if $breakpoint == mac13 {

    @media screen and (width: 1366px) and (height: 768px) {

        .button_text{
            font-size: 0.8rem;
        }
    }
        
    }

    @if $breakpoint == ipad11pro_port {

        @media screen and (height: 1112px) and (width: 834px) {

            body {
                font-size: 70%;
            }


            .name_text{
                font-size: 2.5rem;
                padding-top: 1rem;
                padding-left: 5vw;
            }

            .role_text{
                font-size: 1.7rem;
                padding-top: 0.6rem;
                padding-left: 1rem;
            }

            .main_div{
                height: 985.3px;
                //height: calc((100vh + (#{$head_div_height} * 2)));
            }

            .photo_box{
                height: 40%;
                width: 100vw;
            }

            .photo{
                margin: 0 auto;
                margin-top: 50px;
                width: auto;
                height: 85%;

            }

            .vk_picture{
                height: $picture_width;
                width: $picture_width;
                margin: auto;
              }
              
              .tg_picture{
                height: $picture_width;
                width: $picture_width;
                margin: auto;
              }
              
              .hh_picture{
                height: $picture_width;
                width: $picture_width;
                margin: auto;
              }

            .contacts_section_col{
                width: calc((#{$picture_width} * 3) / 3);
            }

            .contacts_section_row{
                margin-top: 1rem;
                width: calc(#{$picture_width} * 3)
            }

            .button_text{
                font-size: 1.3rem;
            }

            .contact_header{
                text-align: center;
                height: auto;
                width: inherit;
                margin: 0 auto;
                margin-top: 1rem;
                transform: translate(0); 
            }

            .skills_container_row{
                font-size: 2.5rem;
                margin: 0px;
            }

            .skillsandprojects-col-one{
                font-size: 2rem;
                height: auto;
                text-align: left;
            }


            .skillsandprojects_container{
                position: absolute;
                top: 40%;
                right: 0;
                left: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 35%;
                margin: 0;
                background-color: white;
                border: none;
            }

            .contacts_section{
                position: relative;
                bottom: calc(100vh - (#{$main_div_height} + #{$head_div_height} + #{$contact_section_height}));
                width: 100vw;
                height: $contact_section_height;
              }


            .skillsandprojects_container2{
                position: absolute;
                top: 75%;
                right: 0;
                left: 0;
                height: 35%;
                width: 100%;
            }

            .skills_container_row3{
                width: 100%;
                height: 39px;
                border: none;
                margin-bottom: 1rem;
              }

        }
            
        }

        @if $breakpoint == ipad11pro_land {

            @media screen and (width: 834px) and (height: 1112px) {

                body {
                    font-size: 1200%;
                }
                .button_text {font-size: 1rem;}
            }
```

}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I figured this.

I haven't made it work the way I planned initially but I guess this will be the best thing to do.

**THE ANSWER**

So apparently Safari doesn't react to media queries with specific resolutions and you have to use ranges with either min or max height or width. Just rewrite your queries and Safari will handle them right

---

Before you throw me a comment - yes, I'm aware that it's not the best practice to put specific resolutions and media queries. I was trying to make this way so I can tailor the design for each resolution. I didn't wanted to expand mobile design for tablets and I did wanted them to keep desktop version in landscape while preserve mobile in portrait.

The easier way to achieve that effect was to aim in specific green sizes - it didn't work out and now I realize that I can achieve the same effect with different queries for width and height.

As a bonus I'm willing to share queries sizes I found perfect for screens from iPhone SE to MacBook Pro 16

```
@mixin respond ($breakpoint){
        
        @if $breakpoint == phone {

           
            @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) and (max-height: 1366px){
                 //this is for phones and tablets in portrait

                
                // query styles go here  }}

    @if $breakpoint == tab_land {

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-height: 1366px){ 
            //query styles go here}
        }}

    @if $breakpoint == mac13 {

        @media screen and (min-width: 1366px) {

            // query styles go here  }}

        @if $breakpoint == mac15 {

            @media screen and (min-width: 1600px) {
    
                // query styles go here  
            }}

            @if $breakpoint == mac16 {

                @media screen and (min-width: 2560px) {
                    // query styles go here  
                }

       

}
```